# Add button to MATLAB figure (not GUI) to exit loop

Tags: matlab, button

I have created a script that enters a while loop acquiring incoming COM port data, and also produces a figure that updates with said data.

Currently, I do not have an elegant way to exit this loop. I would like to be able to add a button of sorts to accomplish this, but my knowledge of the subject is hazy.

I do not really want to create a GUI, wondering if I can slap a button on my figure.

What I have tried:

Created a separate m-file to house a button-press call-back to get the button state:

```
function [button_state] = fun1(hObject, eventData)
    button_state = get(hObject, 'Value');
end
```

Within the while loop I have the following button declaration, where 'fig' is my figure plot:

```
while 1 > 0

    ...

    fig = figure(1);

    ...

    tb = uicontrol(fig, 'Style', 'togglebutton', 'String', 'Stop', 'Callback', @fun1);

    out = fun1(tb);
    if out == 1
        break;
    end

end
```

Doesn't seem to work... Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the logic seems fine ... what doesn't work exactly? do you get an error? does `Value` not get the value you expect? Is the function never called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find yourself create any object in the main loop, then most likely you are not doing the right thing: Here, in every iteration of the loop, you create a new togglebutton. It is not quite visually noticeable though because they are repetitively created at the same location. As a matter of fact, your code can work if you are able to click quick enough so that the click finishes before this button is overwritten by the next.

You should instead create togglebutton outside the loop, also it is not necessary to use a callback if you are just interested in its `Value` property. Also, you need to use `drawnow` or a `pause` at various places to make sure all events get properly handled:

```
fig = figure(1);
tb = uicontrol(fig, 'Style', 'togglebutton', 'String', 'Stop');
drawnow;
while true
    drawnow;
    if (get(tb, 'Value')==1); break; end
end
close all
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you have a couple problems.

1. You are creating the button inside the while loop, so it's creating itself over and over again.
2. You give it a callback AND call the callback directly. In this case, you don't even need a callback function since pressing the button changes the Value property.

You can accomplish your goal by creating the button and then checking its value directly inside the loop.

Here's some code that does what you want:

```
fig = figure(1);
tb = uicontrol(fig, 'Style', 'togglebutton', 'String', 'Stop');

while true % loop for forever
    drawnow %this command makes sure background functions (callbacks) run
    if tb.Value == 1 %read the value of the uicontrol
    % alternatively use: if get(tb, 'Value') == 1    
        break;
    end
end
```

EDIT: Here is an even simpler way to do this

```
fig = figure(1);
tb = uicontrol(fig, 'Style', 'togglebutton', 'String', 'Stop');

while tb.Value == 0 % loop until button is pressed
    % do stuff
    drawnow % run background functions
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a global variable (for example `stoploop`).

Modify your function `fun1`:

```
function [button_state] = fun1(hObject, eventData)
    global stoploop
    stoploop = (get(hObject, 'Value')==1);
    % in new version of MATLAB
    % stoploop = (hObject.Value==1);
end
```

and main script:

```
global stoploop
stoploop = false;

...

fig = figure(1);
tb = uicontrol(fig, 'Style', 'togglebutton', 'String', 'Stop', 'Callback', @fun1); 
% declaration of button inside while-loop is not necessary

while true

    ...

    if stoploop 
       stoploop = false;
       break
    end

end
```

for `while`-loop you can use short version:

```
while ~stoploop 

    ...

end
```

Answer (score -1):

actually I think you should add your codes into fun1.m because the fun1.m will refered if you press the button as you add the callback property on the button.Personally I don't advice that you deal with GUI with while loop.